# InputGesture modifier for "Windows" key

Tags: wpf

This is a simple question.

If I want to set the shortcut for one of my commands to Windows V, what string do I use for the "Windows" key modifier?

```
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Command="vm:MainVM.OpenDialogCommand" Key="V" Modifiers="**WHAT DO I PUT HERE**"/>
</Window.InputBindings>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.modifierkeys.aspx). Just use Modifiers="Windows".

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.modifierkeys.aspx), `Modifiers="Windows"`.